# Couldn't find User with id= (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With my rails app I can successfully create an object (called work; think of them as blog posts) as current_user. A user has_many works. I can validate that the object is created successfully by checking the database using my postgresql browser. The table also holds the correct user_id that created the work so I know that my create function works in my controller.

However, the problem is that when I try to view the work, I get the following error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WorksController#show

Couldn't find User with id=23

app/controllers/works_controller.rb:43:in `show'

What's odd is that I can still view works that I created several weeks ago. The error only appears for works that I have created recently.

Here's the Works controller:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController
   #before_filter :current_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @works = Work.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @works }
end
end
def create
    @work = current_user.works.create(params[:work])
    redirect_to current_user
  end

def edit
    @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @work = current_user.works.new
end

def destroy
  @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Work deleted"
  redirect_to current_user
end

 def update
    @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
    if @work.update_attributes(params[:work])
      flash[:success] = "updated"
      redirect_to @work
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @work = @user.works.find(params[:id])
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Work", trackable_id: @work).all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm assuming the error is in the Works controller. What do I need to edit in the controller in order to fix the "show" errors?

EDIT: If I use the current code above, I can only view other people's works (viewing my own throws an error). However, if I add current_user into the query (such as @works= current_user.works), I can then only see my own works. Viewing other people's works throws an error. How can I fix this so that I can view both my own works and works created by others?

EDIT 2:

@work = Work.find(params[:id]) works if I remove @user from the controller and the "@user" references in the works show.html view file. However, I need the "@user" reference in the controller because I want to display the name of the user that created the work. How should I go about doing this?

EDIT 3:

**FIXED! Thanks again to everyone who contributed their answers! Here's what I did to fix it:**

1. I removed the @user reference from the controller ("show" action). As Fred mentioned below the @user reference is not needed and needed to be removed since I was using :id twice to reference two separate objects.
2. Edited the "@work" variable to `@work = Work.find(params[:id])`. This will look for the correct work item based on the id regardless of which user created it.
3. When I need to display the user data on the work pages, simply use `<%= @work.user.name %>` on the show.html.erb view page. '@user = User.find(params[:id])' is not needed since I already defined a foreign key relationship on the works model by using 'belongs_to :user'.

Thanks again for all of the help!
-j

Comment: Why are you querying with 

`@user.works with a find()`

You should just need to use 

`@work = current_user.works`

Comment: Right, id can't do double duty as the record id of the user and the record id of the work to be displayed. If you know the id of the work, just find that record by id (Work.find(params[:id]) as in answer 2). If you don't know the Work id at the time you make the show request, you'll need to rethink how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your show action, get rid of @user all together and just use:

```
@work = Work.find(params[:id])
```

This will allow anyone to view any work.

Same goes for your other actions.  By saying:

```
@work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
```

you are searching through all the current_user's works for a work with `id == params[:id]`.

Comment: Hi pricey, thanks for the reply. This works if I remove @user from the controller and the "@user" references in the works show.html view file. However, I need the "@user" reference in the controller because I want to display the name of the user that created the work. How should I go about doing this? Thank you so much for the help so far!

Comment: Figured it out! All I needed was <%= @work.user.first_name %>! Thanks again for the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are using the `work_id` instead of `user_id` when looking up the user and so it works sometimes but is the wrong ID.

You are in the works controller.  params[:id] is the work.

so this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@work = @user.works.find(params[:id])
```

should probably be this:

```
@user = User.find(current_user)
@work = @user.works.find(params[:id])
```

If you just want all the works use

```
@works = Work.all
```

since you can use the same params[:id] as te id to look up both user and work.  If they are the same ID it's just a coincidence.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the reply! I changed the code but now I get this error instead: Couldn't find User without an ID. Am I getting closer?

Comment: This doesn't work when I'm logged in as one user and I'm trying to view work made by someone else. This code works when I want to view work that I created, but when I view someone else's work I get an error: Couldn't find Work with id=1 [WHERE "works"."user_id" = 3]

Comment: How do you determine the id of the other user?

Comment: Run the rails console (`script/rails console`) at the command line and then do User.all

Comment: or just `rails c` and then  `User.all` with current versions of rails

Answer (score 1):

I found using current_user.works.find_by(id: params[:id]) works returning a nil when nothing is found.

I think this is a little better as you could now use current_user in your look up to be a little safer as you do not have to rely on your view to not show data that it should not because it never gets it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are deleting a user and are left with the dangling references to `works`

By querying for works with

`@work = @user.works.find(params[:id])`

you are looking for all of @user's works which belong to the @user (redundant)

If you instead use `@work = @user.works` those dangling works references won't be touched since @user.works will return an empty response.

This is really not the best solution though, you need to better handle the destruction of dependencies when a user is deleted.

EDIT: Sorry, I used current_user where I should have used @user, comment above has same error.

Comment: Hi Ethan, thanks for the reply! The problem is that I haven't been deleting any users. I just tried your query, created a new work, tried to access it and I'm still getting the same error. I'm not using current_user.works.find because I want everyone to see the work object regardless of who made it. For example, I want everyone to be able to view http://appURL/works/24 . I use current_user.works on the Users controller to list all of that user's works.