# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, Couldn't find Empower with 'id'=14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Although some of the Questions are very close to the problem i am facing but solution is not working for me. like this one [Couldn't find User with id= (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693479/couldnt-find-user-with-id-activerecordrecordnotfound)

I am doing before action for finding app like this

```
before_action :find_empower, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

here is my **destroy** method in controller:

```
def destroy
    @empower.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to empowers_url, notice: 'successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


private

  def find_empower
    @empower = Empower.find(params[:id])
  end
```

but whenever I am deleting it raises an exception:

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound**

**Couldn't find Empower with 'id'=14**

Even when i am redirecting it to `empowers_url` it is still trying to hit `"empowers/14"` where 14 is the id of the list which i am trying to delete.

On Rails Console:

```
   > Empower.find(14)
      Empower Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "empowers".* FROM "empowers" WHERE "empowers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 14]]
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Empower with 'id'=14
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:154:in `find'
        from (irb):1
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/abhinay/rails_project/iSupportWomen/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/abhinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Empower model:

```
class Empower < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments

  has_many :paths
  has_many :notes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paths, 
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? },
                                allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, 
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['step'].blank? },
                                allow_destroy: true

  validates :category, :title, :description, :image, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image,
  :storage => :dropbox,
  styles: { :medium => "300x300>"},
  :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox_config.yml"),
  # :dropbox_options => { :path => proc { |style| "#{Rails.env}/#{style}/#{id}_#{image.original_filename}" } },
  :unique_filename => true
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  # has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "300x300>" }


end
```

**Update:**

It turnout to be an issue with routing itself, i had another page called and I had modified my route root path to home, `root "empowers#home"` but after changing it to `root "empowers#index"` deleting record seems to be working again. if anybody has an answer to this then i would really like to know.

Comment: What is the output of Empower.find(14) in rails console ?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed updated question with console output

Comment: So, you don't have any record with id 14, and still you are trying to destroy it? Or am I not getting you?

Comment: so the problem is , when i click on delete record, it keeps on loading and after few seconds it raises this ActiveRecord not found exception. so I dont know why it is even trying to look for this record when i have redirected to empowers_url

Comment: Could you please add the Empower model here?

Comment: Are you using any cancan?

Comment: updated model empower.

Comment: no I am not using cancan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71896/discussion-between-sharvy-ahmed-and-abhinay).

Comment: The real problem appears to be that the `empowers_url` URL helper method is returning `/empowers/<The_Id_That_Just_Got_Deleted>` instead of `/empowers/`. This feels like there is some Chicken Voodoo Magic going on with the URL helpers. Try `redirect_to :index`. If that works, I wonder if the `@empower` instance variable is being used by the URL helper method.

Comment: @GregBurghardt let me try that and get back to you

Comment: Did you anyhow changed empowers_url route ?

Comment: @GregBurghardt nope same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. You just don't have an Empower with and ID of 14 in your DB. If you want to see the Empowers in your db, you could do something like this in your rails console:

```
Empower.all.each do |e|
  puts e.id
end
```

My guess is that you did successfully delete that Emopower (with ID of 14), but you had a view or controller error that occurred after the fact. So it got deleted, you fixed the error, but you are trying to delete the same thing (that isn't in your db any more).

Comment: Actually its happening for all records not just one record with id=14

Comment: so whenever i am trying to remove anyother record it is throwing an exception record not found.

Comment: what happens when your run the above code in rails console? Do any id's get printed out?

Comment: yes all the records which present like 11, 10 etc..but when i tried deleting 10 it throws an exception record not found, and after a page refresh record doesn't show up, which i think is getting deleted but why this Exception i dont understand

Comment: Can you paste your Empowers#index view? There is something in there that you are doing that is throwing the error. So what is happening is this:

1. you hit delete
2. Rails hits controller, deletes the item (totally from the db), then returns you back to Empowers index.
3. Something in the index is looking for that item again, but it is gone.
4. You go back to try and find it in console, but it is gone too.

So it isn't an error in your controller or delete method. It is somewhere in your index method or view

Comment: but its not even reaching to index, it is trying to go the show page of same record, like "empower/14"

Comment: According to the destroy method, it should redirect to the index. See ```format.html { redirect_to empowers_url, notice: 'successfully destroyed.' }``` . The empowers_url should be redirecting back to ```empowers#index``` unless you changed something in your routes file

Comment: exactly thats what i cant understand, if it would have been trying to go to index, then this Exception will never come up..its only because its trying to go to show page of the deleted record causing this error.

Comment: Can you post your routes file then?

Comment: Or a copy of the output from running rake routes